# How to add a photo as a background for a div in rails with @media query?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

The following works correctly in `view` file `home.html.erb`

```
<stlye>
.wrapper {
   background: url(<%= asset_path 'home.jpg' %>);
}
</style>
```

However, when I attempt the following in the my `home.css.scss` file:

```
@media (max-width: 350px) {
  .wrapper {
   background: url(<%= asset_path 'home-ip5.jpg' %>);
  }
}
```

it will not push to Heroku. It throws an error:

> remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...ackground: url(": expected ")", was "<%= asset_path ..."

These images are located at `app/assets/images/home.jpg` and `app/assets/images/home-ip5.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sass-rails, you should be able to do something like

```
url(asset-path('example.jpg'))
```

i.e.

```
background: url(asset-path('example.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the code above to work by running the following:

```
rake assets:precompile
```